# Overloading the __str__ method in the inherited class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

So I have 2 classes defined as follows:

```
Class A:
  def __init__(self)
      self.A = None
      #Constructor initializes varA to None
  def setValues(self, A) 
  def __str__()
     return something1        # Belongs to A

Class B(A):
  def callA():
     self.setValues(x)           # This calls setValues in A.
  def __str__()
     return something2          # Belongs to B
```

In the `main()`, I would like to print `something1` of the class `A` which has been initialised in `B`. How can I do this?

Comment: What? That isn't even valid Python. Where are you expecting `something1` and `something2` to come from? What are you actually asking; rather than the abstract example, *what are you trying to achieve*?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> b = B()
>>> print A.__str__(b)
something1
```

Answer (score 2):

In class B, you can define a method that will return A's `__str__` like so:

```
def str_A():
  return super(B, self).__str__()
```